# What design pattern can I use to emulate traits / mixins in PHP?

Tags: php, design-patterns, traits

Since traits aren't available in PHP 5.3 AFAIK I need to emulate some of the functionality they offer. Interfaces won't work because I need concrete functionality.

### Problem:

I have two client classes that need to share some functionality but extend from different base classes.

```
ClassA extends Foo {}

ClassB extends Bar {}
```

I need to be able to implement a function called getComponent() in both classes and it needs to be functionality identical.

Changing the base class is not an option. I was thinking to do something like this:

```
Class ComponentHandler {
  function getInstance() {
    //return singleton
  }

  function getComponent() {
   //required functionality
  }
}

Class A extends Foo {

  var $handler;

  function __construct() {
    $this->handler = ComponentHandler::getInstance();
  }
}
```

I would implement this constructor in both ClassA and ClassB. In my client I would make calls like this:

```
$class = new ClassA();
$class->handler->getComponent();

$class = new ClassB();
$class->handler->getComponent();
```

Comment: I think that the approach you've proposed is actually the way to go (it's called [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), by the way).

Comment: Please clarify the ClassA and Class A syntax by adding the required space(s) respectively.  Agreed with @Brian - what you have is not only adequate but better than introducing more DI using Galen's suggested implementation (tho classic and still useable) [below].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer to pass objects via the constructor whenever possible. Your method has a dependency on the Class Name `ComponentHandler`.  By passing the object via the constructor and adding a [type hint](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) you are still adding a dependency, but one that allows you to create different type of `ComponentHandler`s

```
Class A extends Foo {
    var $handler;
    function __construct( ComponentHandler $handler ) {
         $this->handler = $handler
    }
}

$componentHandler = ComponentHandler::getInstance();
$class = new ClassA( $componentHandler );
```

Class can take any handler that extends ComponentHandler, this will work too...

```
Class ComponentHandler2 extends ComponentHandler {}
$componentHandler = ComponentHandler2::getInstance();
$class = new ClassA( $componentHandler2 );
```

Comment: I was wondering what to do about the dependency. Thanks for your help.